# Notcing that a lot of sites, on my new MacBook have dithered graphics, how as a desinger would I tackle that?

Tags: interface-design

With my new MacBook, lots of sites now show lousy graphics (attached), and it looks like no one is tackling that issue.

Question: To have crystal clear, pixel perfect graphics for any site, as a designer, what graphics specs should I be working with in the way of size, resolution, palette, and best saving tips? And do I now need to really have 2 graphics for every site? Retina and non-retina? Seems kind of crazy. Solutions most welcome.

[image]

Comment: I feel like this is a really broad question

Comment: It's what you said. If you have a retina display, most of the internet still uses standard res graphics. This will change with time. You can change your screen resolution scale. As a designer you can use photoshops export options to make both versions oh an asset for web design.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, that's not dithering. That's anti-aliasing you are seeing.

Secondly, if you have a retina screen macbook, a lot of web site graphics will look like that because not all sites are sending you the higher resolution retina images.

> To have crystal clear, pixel perfect graphics for any site, as a designer, what graphics specs should I be working with in the way of size, resolution, palette, and best saving tips?

There's no one answer to this. This is simply too broad of a question, but...

> And do I now need to really have 2 graphics for every site?

If you want to support higher-density screens like 2x and 3x retina displays, then you need images that support those 2x and 3x screens.

> Seems kind of crazy. Solutions most welcome.

Solutions include:

- not worrying about it. People will still see  images. Just not as crisp as they could be.
- create separate images as needed.
- create just the highest resolution image (lower resolution screens will still see it just fine...the only drawback is that you are forcing people with lower resolution screens to spend the bandwidth downloading pixels they can't see).
- try using resolution-independent vector files (SVG, icon fonts, etc.)

Comment: Creating 2x graphics is one solution. I say worry about it though. If you're designing a website, you should consider 2x assets for static images such as the example provided. However, the best solution (IMO) is creating an icon font **or** using SVGs. Though if you create SVGs you might as well follow through with making an icon font. You can use SVGs to create an icon font for free, using [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/)

Comment: The entire idea that the browser auto doubles image size is so wrong on many dimensions.

Comment: @joojaa how so? How else would they handle it?